Change border color of CTabItem
Currently, in my RAP application, the border of the widget in focus gets white, and the users think this is not visible enough and want it to be changed to a more obvious color. I have been playing around with CSS and code all the afternoon, but I can't figure it out.
In CSS first, I tried something like:
CTabItem: selected {
    background-color: red;
}

But that changes the color of the opened tab of all the views, not just the focused one... Which gets overriden and stays white. I tried all combinations from the reference I found here, but no luck.
Then, I tried accessing the CTabFolder and CTabItem elements directly from the code. I managed to get them, and did something like that:
// Note: getColor is a custom method to get Color objects from CssColor ones

CTabFolder tabFolder = ... // Code to get CTabFolder
tabFolder.setSelectionBackground(
    new Color[] {getColor(CssColor.create(255, 0, 0)), getColor(CssColor.create(0, 255, 0))},
    new int[] {50},
    false
);

That works... But only changes the colors in the tab, not the border.
I am now out of ideas, suggestions or solutions are welcome !

Personally, I found my experience in RAP to be a "customization" hellscape until resolving to build a multitude of custom widgets, many of which led to extending a single parameter and a pseudo generic-typing avalanche.
That being said, CTabFolder constructor uses rwt.html.Border(, 